# onclick check box back ground colour change of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have made an information card and in the top right hand corner there is a check box, within the info card div. The objective is when the check box is checked the background colour of the info card div changes with a fade. Can't seem to get it to work. any help would be appreciated. Code here https://jsfiddle.net/wptq9sfk/:

HTML:

```
<div class="pin" id="pin"> 
<div class="pull-right intrest-box">
<input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" id="like" ><label></label> 
</div>    
<p class="pull-left">13.01.16  </p> <!-- date -->     
<h2>Title </h2> <!-- title-->   
<p> </p>
<div class="text-center">    
<p class="card-title"><a href="" class="">Like</p></a>        
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#like").click(function () {
$("#pin").toggleClass("pincard-checked");
});    
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
.pincard-checked{background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff;}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wptq9sfk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the document.ready function, also you have missed your own pin-checked css in the JSfiddle that you posted. i have updated your code and run in codePen. Please find the link below. Code is working fine.

http://codepen.io/johnsonshara/pen/obGjGN

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#like").click(function () {
    $("#pin").toggleClass("pincard-checked");
  });
});
```

Comment: I'll post a new question regarding this, but thought I would ask. How can I makes it so that the highlighting is saved even if the page is refreshed and if the page is sent as a link?

Comment: for that you need maintain a state of that checkbox, if the checkbox is ticked keep the highlight on or else don't keep. you can keep the state using localStorage or sessionStorage. have a look on it once.

Comment: Thanks so much, will have a look at a few turorials http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34812590/how-to-create-local-storage

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="card-title"><a href="" class="">Like</p></a>
```

Didnt you change up the p and a closing tag?

---

**Edit:**

Also, I think it would be better to use "onchange" function on the checkbox, instead of "onclick"

Something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="togglingCheckbox(this)" .....>
```

This way you can detect if the checkbox state is changed with keyboard, not only with mouse.

Comment: What do you mean change up?

Comment: <p class="card-title"><a href="" class="">Like</a></p>
should look like this, first close the tag you opened the last, the closing tags should be in reverse order than the opening tags

Comment: </p> should be at the end, not </a>. On another note, I'm not sure this fixes your problem. Let me play with the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place your javascript inside

```
$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

Because it is needed for Jquery