# How to pass values from one web page to another

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to web development and there is something I'm very use to doing in mobile dev and I wanted to know if it is applicable to web development(Html, CSS & Javascript).
It is basically code reuseability, but in this case I want to pass the data(String) I get from a database to another web page where I act on those data.

I would like to implement It with a single web page whose job is to load the data e.g a web page that shows user profile or a web page that show chat history of 2 users.

I really hope you understood what I was trying to say, I honestly suck at type explaining.
Thanks guys.

A code example of what I'm trying to implement.
example language Flutter(dart).

```
...
final string userId;
const ShowUserProfile(this.userId);
....
Text('Welcome ${widget.userId} to your profile screen', style: ....);
....
```

Comment: Url query params, or post body query params, are two of the most basic ways of passing data from one page to another.

Comment: @Taplar thanks, so how do I get the strings from the URL in the destination web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass data from one page to another using only HTML, and JS (client-side) code and not use any server-side code you can accomplish this in two ways:

1) Store data in the URL. Example:

HTML

```
<a href="/someurl" id="mylink">some link</a>
```

JS

```
const data = 'abc';
const link = document.getElementByID('mylink');
link.href += '?data='+ data;
```

this method is detailed in another question here [How to store data as a url parameter using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817091/how-to-store-data-as-a-url-parameter-using-javascript)

2) The preferred method is to store the data as a cookie in the user's browser because this method does not pass the data over the network. Example:
JS

```
document.cookie = "data=abc";
```

Comment: for the first and second solution, how do I get the data when I want to use them?

Answer (score 0):

Two methods, one is the data can be part of the http link such as https://yourwebsite/iampage/thisisthevalue. But this method is so messy and your users will see the value and also spaces are replaced with %20....

Method 2 is using localStorage or session or indexedDB. Easiest is localStorage. More information on localStorage can be found in this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.

Comment: I don't think these options are the most usable ones. Considering the question author is a beginner i would rather recommend the use of @Taplar 's idea in the questions comments. Also localStorage is only accessible to websites with the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a separate css document with all the code and then go like this:

```
<source src="name.css" type="text/css">

Then you can get the same CSS document on 2 diffrent pages
```